# Use a stack to check .txt file for ('s, {'s, ['s, etc - Java

Tags: java, file, stack

I am trying to write a method in java to search a text file that I imported for specific characters. The file is actually a java program that I designed and converted to a `.txt` file.

When an opening brace/bracket is found, I am supposed to add (push) it to a stack and then when a corresponding closing brace/bracket is found I am supposed to remove (pop) it from the stack.

The purpose is to see if I have the correct amount of `)`, `}`, `]` and `>` to correspond with the `(`, `{`, `[` and `>`. If they all match up the method should return true, if they don't it should return false.

Anyone know how I can write this?

Comment: Well, you have all the algorithm right there...

Comment: high level... read the file line by line. for each character in each line, look for opening/closing brackets/parenthesis/curly braces and do the stack stuff you described in you question. at the end of the file, your stack should be empty

Comment: Having trouble actually implementing that to code. Been studying all day for another class so I'm a little slow right now...

Comment: Bryan, homework queries should be tagged as such.

Comment: which part of it is troubling... reading a file, parsing a file, reading characters in a line, using the stack?

Comment: Finding the specific characters in the file is what I am struggling with right now.

Comment: Once you have a line, can you scan it for characters somehow?

Comment: what have you tried so far? please post some code. btw, finding specific characters could be done by reading the file line by line and checking each character of each line. that should be easy to implement (string.charAt). A better way would be to read the file byte by byte and checking each character, but reading lines would be a good start I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the sample implementation for balancing the brackets in a input text file

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Stack;

public class BalanceBrackets {
    private Stack<Character> symbolStack;

    public void balance(String inputText) {
        symbolStack = new Stack<Character>();
        for (int index = 0; index < inputText.length(); index++) {
            char currentSymbol = inputText.charAt(index);
            switch (currentSymbol) {
            case '(':
            case '[':
            case '{': 
                symbolStack.push(currentSymbol);
                break;

            case ')':
            case ']':
            case '}':
                if (!symbolStack.isEmpty()) {
                    char symbolStackTop = symbolStack.pop();
                    if ((currentSymbol == '}' && symbolStackTop != '{')
                            || (currentSymbol == ')' && symbolStackTop != '(')
                            || (currentSymbol == ']' && symbolStackTop != '[')) {
                        System.out.println("Unmatched closing bracket while parsing " + currentSymbol + " at " + index+1);
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Extra closing bracket while parsing " + currentSymbol + " at character " + index+1);
                    return;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!symbolStack.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("Insufficient closing brackets after parsing the entire input text");
        else 
            System.out.println("Brackets are balanced");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D://input.txt"));
        String input = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(input);
        }
        new BalanceBrackets().balance(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post complete solutions for questions marked "homework" - it usually doesn't actually help the OP to learn anything.

Comment: @Mac Thanks for the suggestion, I will keep in mind. OP got the entire algorithm in his question itself, that was the reason I posted the code for for it.