# remove paired brackets({},(),[]) and text within it and replace the remaining unpaired with space in a string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, spaces, brackets

I have some strings and the expected output after string manipulation,

String  ab = (abc)def ->def  //returns the string after removing the paired brackets and text within it.

String  cd = abc(def ->abc def  //replace the unpaired brackets with spaces.

String  ef = abcdef) ->abcdef  //replace the unpaired brackets with spaces.

String  gh = (abc)def(xyz) ->def  //returns the string after removing the paired brackets and text within it.

String  ij = ((abc)def(xyz)) -> empty //returns empty string as the paired brackets and the text within them are removed.

String  kl= (abc)def(xyz(abc)  ->def xyz //removes paired brackets and text within and returns rest.

I need to do the following string manipulation to the string provided.

For paired brackets (),{},[] the brackets and the text inside them are to be removed and the unpaired ones have to be replaced with a space .
I tried with many regex and setting counter.But was not working as expected.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: " I tried with many regex and setting counter." Post what you have tried..

Comment: str = str.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\) ?", "");  ,str.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "");

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116924/use-a-stack-to-check-txt-file-for-s-s-s-etc-java for a start. I'm not sure what you want to do with cases such as `[a(cd]ef)`, though

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve this task with single regex in java, as recursive regex are not supported in java (although they are in perl).

The right way to solve this task - is to follow Karthik Jeganathan solution - e.g. create simple code to parse the string youself.

Although you can combine regex with while loop to solve this problem. I must warn you that this would be terribly inefficient. Here is the code:

```
int previousInputLength = 0;
String input;
while(input.length() != previousInputLength) {
     previousInputLength = input.length();
     input = input.replaceAll("\\([^()]*\\)", "");
}
input = input.replace("(", " ").replace(")", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use a stack to push characters
2. when pushing a closing bracket then pop till the beginning bracket
3. at end of all characters pop till the beginning bracket and push a space
   repeat till the stack is empty.

Comment: can u explain with an example.